# Rails logs in staging are only writing to my log files. How do I get them to log to STDout or papertrail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this issue that when there's an error, the logs in my terminal aren't informative. The logs are only writing to the log files but my terminal output doesn't show anything. This was super confusing. How do I change this?

What is the Rails default behavior anyway when it comes to logging?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, by default, each log is created under Rails.root/log/ and the log file is named after the environment in which the application is running.

But if you want to change you can specify something like below in config/application.rb which would throw out logs on STDOUT.

`config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

See the [**Rails guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) for more info.

What I usually found easy was to tail the log on console like `$ tail -f log/development.log` and force/see the output of log file on console.